# pandas color column based on value of iother column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, background-color

I want to make a conditional formatting, which is applied on another column in a pandas dataframe. So I want to change the font-color to blue in column " START DATA FACT", if value in column "v" is greater than 0.
I used below code but i need to color another column:

```
        def highlight_col_val(col):
            if col.name in col_background_name:
                return ['background-color:blue' if val == 1 else '' for val in col]
            else:
                return ['' for _ in col]
st = self.df.style.hide_columns('V').apply(highlight_col_val, axis=0)
```

I attempted to do this by doing the following, but it doesn't work:

```
        def highlight_col_val_two(col):
            if col.name in col_background_name:
                    return ['background-color:blue' if val == 1 and col.name == 'START DATA FACT' else '' for val in col]
            else:
                return ['' for _ in col]
st = self.df.style.hide_columns('V').apply(highlight_col_val_two, axis=0)
```

I've explored the style.apply approaches, but can't seem to find one that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

I attempted to do this by doing the following, but it doesn't work

```
        def highlight_col_val_two(col):
            if col.name in col_background_name:
                    return ['background-color:blue' if val == 1 and col.name == 'START DATA FACT' else '' for val in col]
            else:
                return ['' for _ in col]
st = self.df.style.hide_columns('V').apply(highlight_col_val_two, axis=0)
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Does it have no effect, the wrong effect, or do you get an error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.